# A question on the usage of the definite article "THE"

Tags: articles

A question on the usage of the definite article "THE"

The sentence below comes from Word Smart II: How to Build a More Educated Vocabulary.

> Federal law requires ***manufacturers*** to demonstrate both the safety and
>   the efficacy of ***new drugs***. ***The manufacturers*** must prove that ***the new
>   drugs*** are efficacious.

The 1st sentence presents both '**manufacturers**' and '***new drugs***' without articles. But in the 2nd sentence both are presented with definite articles.

Is there any specific reason for this or no good reason so the 2nd sentence is no problem without articles?

Comment: ‘The manufacturers’ in the second sentence refers to those manufacturers mentioned in the first sentence. Likewise with the other term.

Comment: I don't understand why this Question belongs here, rather than in English Language Learners.

Either way, why on Earth would you trust someone who published something with a title including *How to Build a More Educated Vocabulary*, please?

Comment: I'm not sure why Mr. Goodwin get so unhappy about the question about a sentence in How to Build a More Educated Vocabulary. I don't think it's a book to hope for the Pulitzer Prize. But it's a book proofread by an editor, published and sold many years by many people and I, as an English learner, think any question is possible in this site if that's about English Language & Usage.